# Subconsulta con eloquent

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Tengo unos usuarios que a su vez tienen asociados ciertos clientes y estos tienen una foto.
Lo que quiero hacer es mostrar solo las imágenes de los clientes que tenga asociado un usuario.

Por ejemplo: yo soy el usuario Juan y tengo asociados los clientes Manuel y Jose. Pues quiero solo ver las imágenes de Manuel y Jose.

En el controlador hago una subconsulta que es primero: Filtrar todos los clientes que tiene asociado un usuario.

Y quiero hacer una consulta que sea buscar las imágenes de esos usuarios ya filtrados.

Lo que no se es como hacer la consulta completa.

Este es mi método en el controlador:

```
public function index(){

    // Se obtiene todos los clientes que tiene asociado el usuario
    $clientes = Cliente::where("user_id", "=", auth()->user()->id);

    // Se filtran las imagenes que tienen los clientes asociados
    $imagenes = Imagen::all()
    ->paginate(5);



    return view('home.index', ['imagenes'=>$imagenes]);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parece que lo que ocupas es una relación: [**Tiene muchos a través de...**](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through)

Pues dado tu enunciado asumo que existen los siguientes modelos:

- User
- Cliente
- Imagen
- Donde un usuario tiene muchos clientes
- Donde un cliente tiene muchas imágenes

Es decir puedes obtener todas las imágenes asociadas a un usuario a través del modelo intermedio que sería cliente.

Entonces en el modelo `Usuario` define una relación de este tipo:

```
class User extends Model
{
    public function images()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(Imagen::class, Cliente::class, 'fk1', 'fk2', 'pk1', 'pk2');
    }

   public function clientes()
   {
       return $this->hasMany(Cliente::class);
   }

}
```

**Parámetros opcionales**

Estos valores no se deben colocar si sigues las convenciones de Laravel para establecer los nombres de las llaves primarias y foráneas.

- fk1, es la llave foránea del modelo intermedio que en este caso es Cliente
- fk2, es la llave foránea del modelo que será relacionado que es Imagen
- pk1, es la llave primaria del modelo User
- pk2, es la llave primaria del modelo intermedio que es Cliente

**Propuesta de consulta**

```
$data = User::with(['images', 'clientes'])->findOrFail(auth()->user()->id);
```

En la consulta que propongo:

- Al modelo User le cargamos con *eager loading* las 2 relaciones que tiene en forma de vector
- Filtramos con `findOrFail` para solamente obtener los datos de las fotos de clientes del usuario que tiene la sesión iniciada

O bien puedes:

- Filtrar primero por el usuario que deseas encontrar
- Acceder a las imágenes que ese usuario tiene asociadas a través de su modelo intermedio que sería clientes:

Consulta:

```
$data = User::findOrFail(auth()->user()->id);
$data->images;
```

**Nota importante**

> Revisa los nombres de modelos pues los coloqué a modo de ejemplo

Comment: Muchas gracias. Diste en el punto gracias por aclarar mi duda.